# Is it feasible to calculate the rate law of the oxidation of ethanol using colorimetry?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

My IB Chemistry class needs to have our Internal Assessment ideas finalized by next week, and I'm torn between a few experiments. I'm considering performing an oxidation of ethanol and potentially using colorimetry to measure the rate of the reaction (I believe using sodium dichromate as the oxidizing agent will create a color change, but I'm not sure if it is measurable enough to calculate kinetics). I'm also considering comparing the rate of the reaction dependent on temperatures, but am unsure about how that would work (potentially with a water bath?). I've also watched some oxidation of ethanol videos (because it's an AS Chemistry practical), but am unsure of how to move forward with it. Please just tell me if it's a feasible experiment or not, I'm quite literally just asking as to make a decision about what to do for this project.

Comment: I don't think it's slow enough to measure its rate like that.